# On some android devices, OS is killing my app in background also app's service is killed by OS

Tags: android, location, android-service, android-location, foreground-service

I developed an app and in it, I am using foreground service.
Whenever user goes to background, after some time, android kills my app and service too.
I am facing this issue on Vivo device, that have its own Android Funtouch OS. These devices have Restrict background power usage option due to which I am facing this issue.
Is there any way to avoid this option, or to any other way to run my service in background in any other condition?
Basically I want to get location in background, is there any way to get location after some time interval?

Comment: Just in case you are not aware of: https://dontkillmyapp.com/vivo

Comment: Is there a setting on that device to add your app to a whitelist of apps that are allowed to run in the background?

Comment: Yes there is an option, but there are different types of options on different devices. So I'm unable to handle it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app will be **terminated by Android** if you do not have enough free memory. You can increase the chance that the app survives in the background if you free up unusable memory. Take a look at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory). **You can use the onTrimMemory event to free unusable memory**:

```
    override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {
         // Determine which lifecycle or system event was raised.
         when (level) {
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN -> {
               // Release any UI objects that currently hold memory.
            }
         }
     }
```

For your location problem [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666126/background-service-in-android-10-to-get-location-in-every-10-minutes)

> Due to the android's limitations for background tasks in post-O
> devices, background services are destroyed by the android system if
> the app is in the background for some time. You should use
> startForeground() in onStartCommand() to start the service as a
> foreground service and also show the notification for the same.

Comment: I am starting service and showing a notification, but as I mentioned, some devices are killing my service too if background power save is on.